# Integer memory allocation/deallocation

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, allocation

Getting the following error:

malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffee85b4338: pointer being freed was not allocated

I thought I allocated and deallocated properly but I must not have. What did I do wrong? It will compile with zero errors and zero warnings but will not print out the last statement (COMPLETE) after the deallocation of memory.

See source code below. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int numOne, numTwo, numThree;

    cout << "When prompted please enter a whole number." << endl;

    //obtain user input for numbers and store to integer variables
    cout << "\nEnter a number: ";
        cin >> numOne;
    cout << "Enter another number: ";
        cin >> numTwo;
    cout << "Enter a third number: ";
        cin >> numThree;

    //print out user's entered numbers as stored in variables
    cout<< "\nThe numbers you entered currently stored as variables are: ";
    cout << numOne << ", " << numTwo << " and " << numThree << endl;

    //create pointers and allocate memory
    int* pointerOne   = new int;
    int* pointerTwo   = new int;
    int* pointerThree = new int;

    //store location of variables to pointers
    pointerOne   = &numOne;
    pointerTwo   = &numTwo;
    pointerThree = &numThree;

    //print out user's entered numbers as stored in pointers
    cout<< "The numbers you entered currently stored as pointers are: ";
    cout << *pointerOne << ", " << *pointerTwo << " and " << *pointerThree << endl;


    //alter user's numbers to show that pointers alter variables
    cout << "\nNOTICE: Incrementing entered values by one! ";
        *pointerOne   = *pointerOne + 1;
        *pointerTwo   = *pointerTwo + 1;
        *pointerThree = *pointerThree + 1;
    cout << "....COMPLETE!" << endl;

    //print out user's entered numbers as stored in variables
        cout<< "\nThe numbers you entered incremented by one shown using variables:  ";
        cout << numOne << ", " << numTwo << " and " << numThree << endl;

    //deallocate memory
    cout << "\nWARNING: Deallocating pointer memory! ";
        delete pointerOne;
        delete pointerTwo;
        delete pointerThree;
    cout << "....COMPLETE!" << endl;

}
```

Comment: `pointerOne   = &numOne;` makes `pointerOne` point to `numOne`. It no longer points to the nameless `new int` you previously created. Just don't `new` or `delete` and your code should be fine.

Comment: Well my project is to use new and delete operator to learn to manage memory. So I'm not sure what I need to do in order to make this proper.

Comment: *Well my project is to use new and delete operator to learn to manage memory.* -- You learn to manage memory by knowing *when* and when not to use `new` and `delete`, not by using `new / delete` in strange and roundabout ways.

Comment: @HashimGari You either want to use `numXXX` local variables that are located on the stack, or use `pointerXXX` that point to allocated dynamic memory. If you write `pointerOne=new Int; pointerOne=&numOne` you allocated one `int`, stores its address in the pointer and then overwrites it with address of local `numOne`. So you lost the address to dynamic int and cannot delete it in the future=memory leak. And never call `delete` on address not returned from `new`.

Comment: So I'm not sure what I need to do. My objective is to store integers into three different variables, create three pointers to point to each value, display the variables and pointers all the while using the new and delete operators....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store user's input into pointers variables that you allocated memory for them, and then use pointers to manipulate their values:

```
int *numOne, *numTwo, *numThree;
numOne = new int;
numTwo = new int;
numThree = new int;

int *pointerOne, *pointerTwo, *pointerThree;
pointerOne = numOne;
pointerTwo = numTwo;
pointerThree = numThree;

cout << "\nEnter a number: ";
cin >> *numOne; // You can use cin >> *pointerOne;
cout << "Enter another number: ";
cin >> *numTwo; // You can use cin >> *pointerTwo;
cout << "Enter a third number: ";
cin >> *numThree; // You can use cin >> *pointerThree;

cout << "\nNOTICE: Incrementing entered values by one! ";
*pointerOne++;
*pointerTwo++;
*pointerThree++;
cout << "....COMPLETE!" << endl;

delete numOne;
delete numTwo;
delete numThree;
```

Comment: Thank you! That was what wasn't clicking in my head for some reason. Creating a variable and allocating memory to that variable right away! Thank you so much!